# Python Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file

Tags: python-2.7

I wanted to make a fancy welcome message for my calculator when i import my calcintro.py it gives me this message:

> SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file calcintro.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

I have read other StackOverflow posts for solutions but they didn't help much.
Any help would be highly appreciated. 
Heres the code:

```
# coding: utf-8
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-



print" ▄████▄   ▄▄▄       ██▓     ▄████▄     ▄▄▄      ▓█████▄  ██▒   █▓\n"
print"▒██▀ ▀█  ▒████▄    ▓██▒    ▒██▀ ▀█    ▒████▄    ▒██▀ ██▌▓██░   █▒\n"
print"▒▓█    ▄ ▒██  ▀█▄  ▒██░    ▒▓█    ▄   ▒██  ▀█▄  ░██   █▌ ▓██  █▒░\n"
print"▒▓▓▄ ▄██▒░██▄▄▄▄██ ▒██░    ▒▓▓▄ ▄██▒  ░██▄▄▄▄██ ░▓█▄   ▌  ▒██ █░░\n"
print"▒ ▓███▀ ░ ▓█   ▓██▒░██████▒▒ ▓███▀ ░   ▓█   ▓██▒░▒████▓    ▒▀█░  \n"
print"░ ░▒ ▒  ░ ▒▒   ▓▒█░░ ▒░▓  ░░ ░▒ ▒  ░   ▒▒   ▓▒█░ ▒▒▓  ▒    ░ ▐░  \n"
print"  ░  ▒     ▒   ▒▒ ░░ ░ ▒  ░  ░  ▒       ▒   ▒▒ ░ ░ ▒  ▒    ░ ░░  \n"
print"░          ░   ▒     ░ ░   ░            ░   ▒    ░ ░  ░      ░░  \n"
print"░ ░            ░  ░    ░  ░░ ░              ░  ░   ░          ░  \n"
```

Comment: Can you double-check that your text editor actually saves the file as UTF-8?

Comment: Seems about right. http://imgur.com/a/6mw2t

Comment: Any feedback on the provided solution?

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2.7 it's necessary to *explicitly* use [Unicode string literals](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type) in source code.

Prefix strings that contain Unicode characters with a small `u`.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

print u" ▄████▄   ▄▄▄       ██▓     ▄████▄     ▄▄▄      ▓█████▄  ██▒   █▓"
print u"▒██▀ ▀█  ▒████▄    ▓██▒    ▒██▀ ▀█    ▒████▄    ▒██▀ ██▌▓██░   █▒"
print u"▒▓█    ▄ ▒██  ▀█▄  ▒██░    ▒▓█    ▄   ▒██  ▀█▄  ░██   █▌ ▓██  █▒░"
print u"▒▓▓▄ ▄██▒░██▄▄▄▄██ ▒██░    ▒▓▓▄ ▄██▒  ░██▄▄▄▄██ ░▓█▄   ▌  ▒██ █░░"
print u"▒ ▓███▀ ░ ▓█   ▓██▒░██████▒▒ ▓███▀ ░   ▓█   ▓██▒░▒████▓    ▒▀█░  "
print u"░ ░▒ ▒  ░ ▒▒   ▓▒█░░ ▒░▓  ░░ ░▒ ▒  ░   ▒▒   ▓▒█░ ▒▒▓  ▒    ░ ▐░  "
print u"  ░  ▒     ▒   ▒▒ ░░ ░ ▒  ░  ░  ▒       ▒   ▒▒ ░ ░ ▒  ▒    ░ ░░  "
print u"░          ░   ▒     ░ ░   ░            ░   ▒    ░ ░  ░      ░░  "
print u"░ ░            ░  ░    ░  ░░ ░              ░  ░   ░          ░  "
```

The newline `\n` however is implicit in what `print` does, you don't need to write it.